# How to add image in image gallery in DevExprees

Tags: devexpress, image-gallery, xaf

I'm using [XAF](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2670). How to add image in image gallery.I want to choose my image.

http://www.picza.net/show.php?id=20120712vvIdvOvdTldvx67961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy. Add the required images to the Images folder located in a module (if there is no such folder, create it).

Related help topic: [Add and Override Images](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2792)